# how to split by hour in highcharts while using x-axis type date range

Tags: ruby-on-rails, highcharts

I am trying to make a chart using Highcharts which shows no of days in the x-axis if the chart is for a week or month. 
Now i want to split the x-axis by "hours" if the chart is for single day.

[See the fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/xaxis/datetimelabelformats/)

```
var checkin_failures_stats = {

        xAxis: {
          type: 'datetime'
        },
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use tickPositioner and calculate your ticks dynamically.

http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.tickPositioner

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you just need to look at the tickInterval property:

- http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.tickInterval

You'll need to know the time span of your chart - you can either specify this directly, or you can get the min and max values from the getExtremes function, and calculate the length of the time of the chart, and set your tickInterval accordingly.

- http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Axis.getExtremes